# Gaining control over process started by an URI in C#

Tags: c#, url, default, process.start

I'm making a program which opens a configured application after with the passed paramters through an url with shell execute. I achieved this with the following:

```
ProcessStartInfo procinfo = new ProcessStartInfo(URI);
procinfo.UseShellExecute = true;
Process App = Process.Start(procinfo);
```

I want to kill this process later after some minutes through this project that I could do by App.Kill() but the problem is that the Process.Start() always returns null if I pass the URI. How could I reach that process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If the address of the executable file to start is a URL, the process
>   is not started and null is returned.
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53ezey2s.aspx

Even if you specify a browser, the process could be a simple handler that sends a message to an existing process (or opens another process) and closes itself immediately.

But you may explicitly launch the browser you want if you know how its process works.

```
Process p = Process.Start(browserExePath, url);
```